# SQL- How to use Stored Procedure to duplicate row with new Primary Key?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have 7 tables - Company, Person, Person_Link, Address, Address_Link, Phone, Phone_Link. I would like to have a Stored Procedure which intakes parameter of comp_companyid, then it can duplicate all the rows in the 7 tables with new primary keys and foreign for each table.

Tables:

1. Company:
   PK - comp_companyid
   FK - comp_primarypersonid, comp_primaryaddressid
2. Person:
   PK - pers_personid
   FK - pers_companyid
3. Person_Link:
   PK - peli_personlinkid
   FK - peli_personid, peli_companyid
4. Address_Link:
   PK - adli_addresslinkid
   FK - adli_addressid, adli_companyid
5. Address:
   PK - addr_addressid
6. Phone:
   PK - phon_phoneid
7. Phone_Link:
   PK - plink_linkid
   FK - plink_phoneid

My effort:

```
    INSERT INTO Company
    (
        Comp_CompanyId, Comp_PrimaryPersonId, Comp_PrimaryAddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy, Comp_CreatedDate, Comp_UpdatedBy, Comp_UpdatedDate, Comp_TimeStamp,
        Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite
    )
    SELECT  @companyId, @PersonId, @AddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy, Comp_CreatedDate, Comp_UpdatedBy, Comp_UpdatedDate, Comp_TimeStamp,
            Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite

    FROM Company
    WHERE Comp_CompanyId = @comp_companyid



    INSERT INTO Person
    (
        Pers_PersonId, Pers_CompanyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy, Pers_CreatedDate, Pers_UpdatedBy, Pers_UpdatedDate, Pers_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @PersonId, @companyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy, Pers_CreatedDate, Pers_UpdatedBy, Pers_UpdatedDate, Pers_TimeStamp
    FROM Person
    WHERE Pers_CompanyId = @comp_companyid



    INSERT INTO Person_Link
    (
        PeLi_PersonLinkId, PeLi_PersonId, PeLi_CompanyID, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy, PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @PersonLinkId, @PersonId, @CompanyId, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy, PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
    FROM Person_Link
    WHERE PeLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid



    INSERT INTO Address_Link
    (
        AdLi_AddressLinkId, AdLi_AddressId, AdLi_CompanyID, AdLi_CreatedBy, AdLi_CreatedDate, AdLi_UpdatedBy, AdLi_UpdatedDate, AdLi_TimeStamp, AdLi_Type
    )
    SELECT @AddressLinkId, @AddressId, @companyId, AdLi_CreatedBy, AdLi_CreatedDate, AdLi_UpdatedBy, AdLi_UpdatedDate, AdLi_TimeStamp, AdLi_Type
    FROM Address_Link
    WHERE  AdLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid



    INSERT INTO [Address]
    (
        Addr_AddressId, Addr_Address1, Addr_Address2, Addr_Address3, Addr_Address4, addr_postcode, Addr_CreatedBy, Addr_CreatedDate,
        Addr_UpdatedBy, Addr_UpdatedDate, Addr_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @AddressId, Addr_Address1, Addr_Address2, Addr_Address3, Addr_Address4, addr_postcode, Addr_CreatedBy, Addr_CreatedDate,
           Addr_UpdatedBy, Addr_UpdatedDate, Addr_TimeStamp
    FROM Address
    LEFT JOIN Address_Link
    ON Addr_AddressId = AdLi_AddressId
    AND AdLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid



    INSERT INTO Phone
    (
        Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
    FROM Phone
    WHERE Phon_PhoneId = @@IDENTITY



    INSERT INTO PhoneLink
    (
        PLink_LinkID, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
        PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type, PLink_PhoneId
    )
    SELECT  @PhoneLinkId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
            PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type, @PhoneId
    FROM PhoneLink
    WHERE PLink_LinkID = @@IDENTITY

    -- EXEC @PhoneId = crm_next_id 14
    -- EXEC @PhoneLinkId = crm_next_id 10208
```

It worked for Company & Person & Person_Link but shows error on the other tables. The error message is:

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Address___533839D503317E3D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Address_Link'." (dbo.Address as well)

It didn't specify phone table's error but phone table wont create any new row. Anyone has any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to know , after inserting the first row in Company (for example), which is the ID of the company you just inserted.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will help you

Comment: Hi there, I have declared and known the nextid. I have edited my post and showed my effort of code that worked for company and person but not others.